# php key in array being changed

Tags: php, arrays

I have this strange issue where, once I submit an array of code it seems to lose its keys.

```
    $data = array(
    'title' => array(
         'en' => 'en test',
         'fr' => 'fr test'
        ),
    'description' => array(
         'en' => 'description en',
         'fr' => 'description fr'
        ),
    );



try {
    $oauth = new OAuth("xxx","xxx",OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
    $oauth->setToken("xxx","xxx");

    // first output of array
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

    $oauth->fetch("http://foobar.com/rest/v1/", $data, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST , array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

    // second output of array
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

    $response_info = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
    header("Content-Type: {$response_info["content_type"]}");
    echo $oauth->getLastResponse();

    //print_r($oauth);
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
    print_r($E);
    echo "Exception caught!\n";
    echo "Response: ". $E->lastResponse . "\n";
}
```

Generated output

```
// first output of array
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [en] => en test
            [fr] => fr test
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [en] => description en
            [fr] => description fr
        )

)
1
// second output of array
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr test
            [1] => en test
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => description fr
            [1] => description en
        )

)
```

As you can see, once the data has been passed the array changes.

Looking at the headers sent to the server, the post data looks like

```
title=fr%20test&title=en%20test&description=description%20fr&description=description%20en
```

The api on the server side doesn't seem to be accepting anything, so I'm thinking that the issue might be with the way the array is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to many issues, most probably your $data variable is passed as a reference to your oAuth library and this library maybe does a sort instead of asort or an array_merge which will remove the keys from the array!

One thing for sure, it is definitely the oAuth library that is causing this. You could do a copy of the data by simply doing:

```
$oauth->fetch("http://foobar.com/rest/v1/", $copy = $data, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST , array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

This will copy the array into $copy and will keep your $data intact. You might want to check why it's altering the data though!

**EDIT**

It's a sort, look at the data, it's sorted in the second var_dump! Sorted in reverse, but it's sorted!